# How to make logging components visible across whole Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, log4j, logback

I'm running Spring Boot and I want to add logging to my application. All examples have the following for the main Application entrypoint:

```
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
```

However, I want the same log variable visible (as Singleton) across all my application components (services, controllers, etc.). How would I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use springs IoC container to achieve this.

just configure a bean like this in a @Configuration cass

```
@Bean
public Logger log() {
   return LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnyClassYouWant.class);
}
```

and inject it with @Autowired in your class

```
class WhatEver {
   @Autowired
   Logger log;

   //...
}
```

Comment: Personally, I believe that this answer is more "clean" spring way of doing this, then accepted one. It's also worth to mention that when `@Bean` is defined its scope is Singleton by default.

Comment: But this way, you still need to define and autowire the logger variable in every class you are going to use it? I'd prefer a solution where all classes in a project has visibility to it, without the need to explicitly define it in every class.

Comment: I added Bean for the logger, set the AnyClassYouWant to be the classname of the Configuration class ("Configuration"), then autowired a logger variable in another class, but it gives error that at least one bean needs to be autowire candidate?

Comment: obviously you have to create the class...or refer to a class you want.

Comment: You can refer to your "Configuration" class directly. But in practice I would recommend you to do it the old way generating a logger everytime you declare a new class, since it is useful to know, which class logged this message during log analysis....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class.. Which contain:

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaticLog.class);
```

And will expose methods to write logs..

Hope that answer your needs